# Angularjs controllers: how to call a controller in another controller?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, requirejs

I have this **list** controller,

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'app'
], function ($,app) {

    app.controller("ListContacts", function($scope,$route,$http){

        $http({
            method: 'GET', 
            url:'php/listContacts.php'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.contacts = response.data;
         });
    });
});
```

And I have this **search** controller as well, and I want to call the **list** controller inside the **search** if `query !== undefined`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'app'
], function ($,app) {

    app.controller("SearchContacts", function($scope,$route,$http){

        console.log($route.current.params.query);
        if($route.current.params.query !== undefined){
            // call the list controller
        }

        $scope.search = function() {
            console.log($('#frmSearchContacts').serialize());
            $scope.contacts = null;

        };

    });
});
```

is it possible?

**EDIT**

My router,

```
define([
    'app',
    'controller/AppCtrl',
    'controller/AppCtrl2',
    'controller/AppCtrl3',
    'controller/ListContacts',
    'controller/AddContact',
    'controller/UpdateContact',
    'controller/SearchContacts'
], function (app) {

    'use strict';
    //console.log(app);

    return app.config(['$routeProvider' , function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/",
        {
            templateUrl: "js/template/app.html",
            controller: "AppCtrl"
        })
        .when("/listcontacts",
        {
            templateUrl: "js/template/list.html",
            controller: "ListContacts"
        })
        .when("/addcontact",
        {
            templateUrl: "js/template/add.html",
            controller: "AddContact"
        })
        .when("/updatecontact/:id",
        {
            templateUrl: "js/template/update.html",
            controller: "UpdateContact"
        })
        .when("/searchcontacts",
        {
            templateUrl: "js/template/search.html",
            controller: "SearchContacts"
        })
        .when("/searchcontacts/:query",
        {
            templateUrl: "js/template/search.html",
            controller: "SearchContacts"
        })
        .when("/:module/:method/",
        {
            templateUrl: "js/template/app.html",
            controller: "AppCtrl2"
        });
    }]);


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not with your controllers, but with the representation of data.

In both your controllers, you've already defined how to get contacts (in the list controller) and how to display 0..n contacts in `js/template/list.html`.

Depending on how that template is setup, you can use it for display and still define your SearchController to populate the contacts:

```
    .when("/searchcontacts",
    {
        templateUrl: "js/template/search.html",
        controller: "SearchContacts"
    })
    .when("/searchcontacts/:query",
    {
        templateUrl: "js/template/list.html", // notice here
        controller: "SearchContacts"
    })
```

This is very similar to how the angular.js [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) displays a list or details of a phone.

If there is something else you need in your search template to be included in the listing, you could extract the contacts listing to another template and use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) to use that repeated template in both  `js/template/search.html` and `js/template/list.html`.

edit:
To better demonstrate what I mean, I've created an [example on plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/z2hz6H?p=info) using the `ng-include` method as both an element and attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Calling controller methods from another controller is actually not a good idea, following  [angular concepts](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts).

In your case one solution is to use common service to get contacts

```
app.factory("contactsService",function(){
     return {
         getContacts: function(){
            return $http({
                method: 'GET', 
                url:'php/listContacts.php'
            });
         }
     }
})
```

And inject it into everything you want:

```
app.controller("SearchContacts", function($scope,$route,$http, contactsService){

    console.log($route.current.params.query);
    if($route.current.params.query !== undefined){
        contactsService.getContacts().then(function(response){
             $scope.contacts = response.data;            
        })
    }

    $scope.search = function() {
        console.log($('#frmSearchContacts').serialize());
        $scope.contacts = null;
    };

});
```

Also you can use events broadcasting, but in my opinion using service is the best solution in this case.

Comment: this is how i originally call the `list` controller on my router `controller: "ListContacts"`

Comment: +1 for suggesting a service. However, I'd avoid using `angular.factory` to define services (or `angular.service` to define factories)

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
$broadcast('eventname', data)
```

in one controller, and receiving it using

```
$on('eventname', function (data) {});
```

in the other.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Could you please show me an example how to use `$broadcast`?